# convert fiddler raw header to curl -X post command

Tags: curl, postman, fiddler

I have this raw header data that i inspected with fiddler

this is the raw header data that i got from inspecing with fiddler

```
POST /devices/discover/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.40:3579
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 47
Origin: http://192.168.1.40
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://192.168.1.40/
```

and when i execute it in the fiddler composer it works, but when i try to convert it to a curl -X POST command, nothing happens.

this is the raw data that i send with fiddler

```
POST http://192.168.1.40:3579/devices/discover/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.40:3579
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 47
Origin: http://192.168.1.40
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://192.168.1.40/

{"switchDiscovery":true,"silentDiscovery":true}
```

however i would like this to get working by sending some sort of curl -X POST command from a terminal

Answer (score 8):

In Fiddler, you can select the request session in the session list and then use `File -> Export -> Selected Sessions -> cURL script`. This will produce `.bat` file containing the curl invocation with the needed parameters.